# editor.css and block-editor.js are not applied even though they are in the theme setup

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm on WordPress Multisite and for some reason, the aforementioned files are not applied and create errors such as missing whitespace between the left side of the screen and the title/blocks. I've disabled all minifications that there might be from Cloudflare and other similar plugins, but that doesn't seem to be what causes the issue.

Link to the code of the theme: https://github.com/Tetrakern/fictioneer/tree/main

How it looks currently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/khduB.png

How it's supposed to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4htR.png

Relevant code from the _theme_setup.php:

```php
add_editor_style( '/css/editor.css' );
```

```php
function fictioneer_enqueue_block_editor_scripts() {
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

  wp_register_script(
    'fictioneer-block-editor-scripts',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/block-editor.min.js',
    ['wp-dom-ready', 'wp-edit-post', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-components', 'wp-editor', 'wp-data', 'jquery'],
    FICTIONEER_VERSION,
    true
  );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'fictioneer-block-editor-scripts' );

  wp_localize_script( 'fictioneer-block-editor-scripts', 'fictioneerData', array(
    'userCapabilities' => $current_user->allcaps
  ));
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'fictioneer_enqueue_block_editor_scripts' );
```

My .htaccess file: https://pastebin.com/tFa6KdXG

Mostly having no idea what I'm doing, but help would be appreciated.